# Wordpress Gutenberg: Attribute overwritten by block duplicate

Tags: javascript, block-editor

For a custom wordpress gutenberg block I've created a list of buttons so that users can add/remove as many as needed. While this works pretty fine one issue occurs: When duplicating a block the duplicate overwrites the array values of the origin block as long as we are in editing mode. After saving and refreshing the page the array values become independent. Is anyone aware of that behaviour?

```
( function( blocks, blockEditor, element, components ) {
    const el = element.createElement,
          Fragment = element.Fragment,
          PanelBody = components.PanelBody,
          PanelRow = components.PanelRow,
          Button = components.Button,
          TextControl = components.TextControl,
          InspectorControls = blockEditor.InspectorControls;

    blocks.registerBlockType( 'my-custom-blocks/test-box', {
        title: 'Test Box',
        icon: 'screenoptions',

        attributes: {
            buttons: {
                type: 'array',
                default: []
            }
        },
        edit: function( props ) {

            const buttons = props.attributes.buttons;

            return [
                el(
                    Fragment,
                    { key: 'fragment' },
                    el(
                        InspectorControls,
                        null,
                        el(
                            PanelBody,
                            {
                                title: 'Buttons'
                            },
                            el(
                                PanelRow,
                                null,
                                el(
                                    Button,
                                    {
                                        isSecondary: true,
                                        label: 'Add',
                                        onClick: function() {
                                            let newButtons = [ ...buttons ];
                                            newButtons.push( { text: 'Lorem Ipsum' } );

                                            props.setAttributes( { buttons: newButtons } )
                                        }
                                    },
                                    el(
                                        'span',
                                        {
                                            className: 'dashicons dashicons-plus'
                                        }
                                    ),
                                    'Add'
                                )
                            ),
                            buttons.length > 0 && buttons.map( function( button, index ) {
                                return el(
                                    PanelRow,
                                    {
                                        key: 'button-' + index
                                    },
                                    el(
                                        TextControl,
                                        {
                                            label: 'Text',
                                            value: button.text,
                                            onChange: function( newText ) {
                                                let newButtons = [ ...buttons ];
                                                newButtons[ index ][ 'text' ] = newText;

                                                props.setAttributes( { buttons: newButtons } )
                                            }
                                        }
                                    )
                                )
                            } )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                el(
                    'div',
                    {
                        key: 'box',
                        className: 'test-box'
                    },
                    buttons.length > 0 && el(
                        'div',
                        {
                            className: 'test-box__buttons'
                        },
                        buttons.map( function( button, index ) {
                            return el(
                                'a',
                                {
                                    key: 'link-' + index,
                                    style: {
                                        padding: '10px',
                                        backgroundColor: '#007cba',
                                        color: 'white',
                                        display: 'block',
                                        textAlign: 'center',
                                        marginBottom: '4px',
                                        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
                                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                                        textDecoration: 'none'
                                    }
                                },
                                button.text
                            )
                        } )
                    )
                )
            ];
        },
        save: function( props ) {

            const buttons = props.attributes.buttons;

            return el(
                'div',
                {
                    className: 'test-box'
                },
                buttons.length > 0 && el(
                    'div',
                    {
                        className: 'test-box__buttons'
                    },
                    buttons.map( function( button, index ) {
                        return el(
                            'a',
                            {
                                key: 'link-' + index,
                                style: {
                                    padding: '10px',
                                    backgroundColor: '#007cba',
                                    color: 'white',
                                    display: 'block',
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    marginBottom: '4px',
                                    fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    textDecoration: 'none'
                                }
                            },
                            button.text
                        )
                    } )
                )
            );
        },
    } );

}(
    window.wp.blocks,
    window.wp.blockEditor,
    window.wp.element,
    window.wp.components,
) );
```

Here is a little demo how the values get overwritten after duplicating. You can see that the values of the first block-buttons get overwritten after changing the duplicate values.

[image]

Comment: The mistake here is to specify the children of the block as attributes, they should instead be blocks. The official buttons block is a good example of doing this, it has a buttons block ( plural ) that can only contain button blocks ( singular ). It also looks like you've hidden large chunks of your code making answering the original question very difficult if not impossible. I know you're trying to only share the relevant parts but without knowing the fix how do you know which parts are relevant?

Comment: also can you be more specific about what you meant by overwrite? Surely if you duplicate a block then the 2 blocks will have identical attributes, after all they're duplicates/copies. Can you ellaborate more on that? Edit your question to include that information as well as the expanded JS code, and err on the side of sharing too much code not too little

Comment: @TomJNowell I did optimise the question to make things clearer.

Comment: I see, my suspicion is that because the code uses objects its not done a proper deep copy, and the original doesn't update when you change the child because it actually does update but it hasn't been re-rendered yet by React, and selecting it forces a re-render of its edit component. Because it's using an object it doesn't immediately recognise that an update is needed either. As you've shared the full block though, I believe it should be trivial to separate out the button into a child button block, which sidesteps this entire problem and adds sorting/spacing/etc

Comment: Although it feels a little bit restrictive using InnerBlocks here is quite a good work around. Thanks for the discussion.